# Traversing more than one has_many relationships and displaying the content each one belongs too. Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, has-many

I am traversing down into 3 has_many relationships within ActiveAdmin to display the information. I want to display the information in a parent, child format. Currently I have an Event, within the Event there are many locations, each location has many dates, each date has many ambassadors (users).

I would like the information to be displayed so I see the locations of the Event, and then the dates separated by the locations and then the ambassadors (users) separated by the dates. 
This is the code I have currently wrote however it is not giving me the parent child display I am looking for.

```
show do

attributes_table do
row :agency
row :name
row :event_details
row :created_at

panel "Locations" do
  attributes_table_for event.event_locations do
    row :label
    row :address
    row :zip
    row :state
    row :country
    row :notes
    panel "Event dates" do
      event.event_locations.each do |r|
        attributes_table_for r.event_dates do
        row :event_date
        panel "Ambassadors" do
            attributes_table_for event.booking.booking_staff do 

                row :ambassador

        end
        end

   end
   end
end
  end
end
    end
active_admin_comments end
```

As you can see with the above code I am not going to get the desired results. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will point you in the right direction. Make sure you change the

```
:attribute_of_event_date
```

and like symbols so they make sense in the context of your data(model). Good luck!

```
panel "Locations" do
  resource.event_locations.each do |event_location|

    attributes_table_for event_location do
      row :label
      row :address
      row :zip
      row :state
      row :country
      row :notes

      panel "Event dates" do
        event_location.event_dates.each do  |event_date|

          attributes_table_for event_date do
            row :attribute_of_event_date
            row :another_attribute_of_event_date
            panel "Ambassadors" do
              event_date.ambassadors.each do |ambassador|

                attributes_table_for ambassador do
                  row :atttribute_of_ambassador
                  row :another_atttribute_of_ambassador
                end
              end

            end
          end

        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```